# replace variables with value in batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, powershell-2.0

I am having a batch file where it has set variable. I would like replace each variable with value.

For ex: My batch file looks like follows

```
Set Sourcefolder=..\..\Release
Set Variable2=/y /R
Set DestFolder=..\..\Output

XCopy %SourceFolder%\Comp1 %DestFolder%\Comp1 %Variable2%
...
...
..
```

Likewise it has many lines. I would like to replace the variables with value. For example
instead of %SourceFolder% it should replace with value ( ....\release)

How to achieve this ? batch file or Powershell script are preferrale

Comment: Why do you want to do that? And what have you tried?

Comment: I am trying to convert my batch file commands to Msbuild commands. This XCopy Sourcefile destinationfile should be converted as <Xcopy> <sourceFile></SourceFile> <DestinationFile></DestinationFile></Xcopy>. I acheived converting it to Xml but since the variables are to be modified in 15 files. I would like to automate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
$script:variables=@{}
gc .\script.bat | %{ if($_ -match "^Set (.+?)=(.+)"){ $script:variables["$($matches[1])"] = $matches[2]}}

$evaluator ={
$group1 = $args[0].groups[1]
$script:variables["$group1"]
}

gc .\script.bat | %{ [Regex]::Replace($_,"%(.+?)%",$evaluator,[Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::none) } |
out-file .\script2.bat
```

Comment: dude , really great. I have given just 2 variables in the question for example. But my script has many variables .. but your script worked like magic...From which book did you learn Powershell buddy? you are playing with regular expression like sachin tendulkar plays with bat

Comment: @Samselvaprabu - Lol, comparing me to Sachin is like the best compliment I have ever received :)

Comment: hi dude. when i am using it with multiple files like follows it fails.Foreach ($f in $File){ 

$script:variables=@{}
gc $f.fullname  | %{ if($_ -match "^Set (.+?)=(.+)"){ $script:variables["$($matches[1])"] = $matches[2]}}
$evaluator ={
$group1 = $args[0].groups[1]
$script:variables["$group1"]
}

gc $f.fullname  | %{ [Regex]::Replace($_,"%(.+?)%",$evaluator,[Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::none) } |
out-file ("E:\copyforbuild\"+$f.basename+"repl"+".txt")
}

Comment: @Samselvaprabu - fails saying what?

Comment: Buddy, I am sorry. In my script , I have executed this in wrong order so it messed up. Your code is just work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$bat = switch -regex -file c:\test.bat
{
    '^set Sourcefolder=.+$' {'set Sourcefolder=....\release'}
    '^set Variable2=.+$' {'set Sourcefolder=/y /R'}
    '^set DestFolder=.+$' {'set Sourcefolder=..\..\Output'}
    '%SourceFolder%' {'....\release'}
    default {$_}
}

$bat | Out-File c:\test.bat
```

Comment: values are specified buddy. for ex: Set Sourcefolder=..\..\Release Sourcefolder is a variable and the value is set right side.

Comment: buddy your answer is easy to understand but it doesn't work for this case. Is it possible for you to make it work for all the variables and values?. (in your answer variable names were hardcoded) It will be useful and easy to understand answer for many other people. thanks in advance